# $\mathbb{NEXP\subseteq(NEXP\cap coNEXP)/poly}\implies \mathbb{NEXP=NEXP\cap coNEXP}$

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

We already know that $NEXP\subseteq EXP/poly\implies NEXP=EXP$. What if we change $EXP$ to $NEXP\cap coNEXP$.

As the title states, prove the statement in the title.

The original proof use the self-reducibility of the searching problem. For a language $L\in NEXP$, the corresponding search problem has its decision version as $L'=\{<x,y>| y$ is a prefix of a certificate for $x\}$. Clearly, $L'$ is in $NEXP$. Then, we brute force all the poly-long advice and plug it in the $EXP$ advice-taking machine to construct a supposed certificate.

Comment: What happens to the proof? Does is still work, or does it break?

Comment: When brute-force searching for the poly-long advice, one can easily plug it in the $EXP$ algorithm. But, how can one use the advice in an $NEXP\cap coNEXP$ machine.

Comment: Perhaps you should include a version of the argument that does work, and explain the problem in extending it.